# Creating html ul li from nested xml element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an xml as -

```
<item name="a">
   <item name="d">
      <item name="g">
          ...
      </item>
      ...
   </item>
   <item name="e"></item>
   <item name="f"></item>
   ...
</item>
<item name="b"></item>
<item name="c"></item>
```

I want to create a ul li tree structure of this xml as

```
a [node]
 d [node]
  g [node]
  .
  .
  .
 e [node]
 f [node]
 .
 .
b [node]
c [node]
```

I guess I would need to make a infinte loop, but finding it difficult to do it in jquery. My jquery would resemble somewhat like this -

```
function createNestedTree(obj) {
  $("#tree").append("<ul></ul>");
  $(obj).children("item").each(function(){
    $("#tree ul").append("<li>"+$(this).attr("name")+"</li><ul id="+$(this).attr("name")+"level></ul>");
    $(this).children("item").each(function(){
       //logic here
    });
  });
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If there is one root, the best wouldn't be to use recursivity and fill a string instead of directly fill the div ? You create a recursive function that returns a string and taking as parameter an item : if the item hasn't children, return "<li>theitemname</li>" else {var nextlevel="<ul>"; for each children(nextlevel=nextlevel+recursivecall(children)) ; nextlevel=nextlevel+"</ul> ; return "<li>theitemname</li>+nextlevel;}. And to initialize it, you call the function on the only root. If there are several roots it's a bit more complicated

Comment: There also are some jQuery plugin that will do it for you : jsTree, dynaTree, ...

Comment: There is only one root node. I have tried `jsTree`. I need to do many customization with check boxes, radio and UI menus in that tree. So I am avoiding jstree as they come with heavy htmls and my experience is that later on becomes slow and complex.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you ?

```
 function jumpdown (obj) {
   if (obj.hasChildNodes()) {
     var nextlevel = "<li>"+$(obj).attr("name")+"</li><ul id='"+$(obj).attr("name")+"level'>";
     for (var i=0 ; i<obj.chilNodes.length, i++)
     {
       nextlevel = nextlevel + jumpdown(obj.chilNodes[i]);
     }
     nextlevel = nextlevel + "</ul>";
     return nextlevel;
   }
   else return "<li>"+$(obj).attr("name")+"</li>";
 }

 jumpdown(mydocumentxml);
```